Question about likelhood function of discriminative models
Im a little confused with the likelihood function. For discriminative models, we have a hypothesis function $h_{\theta}(x) = p(y \mid x ; \theta)$. Using the principles of maximim likelihood we want to find $\theta$ that maximizes the probability of seeing the data hence:
$$\prod p(x, y) = \prod p(y \mid x) p(x)$$
However in my machine learning textbook the likelihood function is presented as $\prod p(y \mid x)$ why is that? They also mention that maximizing said function is the same as the true likelihood but that doesn't really make much sense to me as $p(x)$ isnt even modeled?? Similarly it wouldn't make much sense to use $\prod p(y \mid x) p(x)$... so I must be missing something. Could someone explain this more clearly?

Better to explain your notations and assumptions explicitly. For example, is the model for $X$  free of $\theta$? Although popular and convenient, the use of symbol $p$ without any subscripts or superscript to represent different functions in many situations may cause confusion.

In this case you can write $\Pi p(y|x) p(x) = \Pi p(y|x) \Pi p(x)$. The question from Zack is fundamental here. In general p(x) dosent depend on $\theta$ so the factor $\Pi p(x)$ is constant when variyng $\theta$. Then the $\theta$ value that maximized $\Pi p(y | x) p(x)$ is the same as the one which maximized $\Pi p(y|x)$. The maximuns achieved are diferent of course but the $\theta$ value is the same in both cases.

Three points:

Your $p(x, y)$ and $p(y \mid x)$ each depend on $\theta$, and you are looking for the value of $\theta$ which maximises the products, so it might be worth including $\theta$ somewhere in your expressions; your question provides a model for the distribution of $y$ given $x$ and $\theta$ so presumably $p(x)$ does not vary with $\theta$

The $\theta$ which maximises $\prod p_\theta(x, y)$ is the same $\theta$ which maximises $\prod p_\theta(y \mid x)$ since each $p(x)$ is unaffected by different values of $\theta$, as @BrianBritosSimmari commented

The likelihood of $\theta$ given the observations $(x,y)$ is only defined up to a positive multiplicative constant since it does not need to sum or integrate to $1$ over $\theta$ (contrast this to probabilities; as numeric values, only likelihood ratios really matter), so $\prod p_\theta(x, y)$ and $\prod p_\theta(y \mid x)$ are each valid expressions for the likelihood of $\theta$ and you can use whichever is more convenient


